# Set State only once

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx, use-effect

I am using a function (getActorInfo()) in react to grab info from an api and set that in a State. It works but the function wont stop running.

```
export default function ActorProfile({ name, img, list, id, getActorInfo }) {
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);
  const [actorInfo, setActorInfo] = useState({});

  getActorInfo(id).then(val => setActorInfo(val));

  console.log(actorInfo)

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Actor
        id={id}
        name={name}
        img={img}
        onClick={() => {
          setShowList(!showList);
        }}
        actorBirthday={actorInfo.actorBirthday}
      />
      {showList && <MovieList list={list} actorInfo={actorInfo} />}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

I tried using useEffect like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getActorInfo(id).then(val => setActorInfo(val));
  }, {});
```

But I get an error that I do not understand

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
>       in ActorProfile (at App.js:60)

My question is how to have this function only run once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything in a functional component body will run every render. Changing to a `useEffect` is the correct solution to this problem.

It isn't working for you because `useEffect` takes an *array* as its second parameter, not an *object*. Change it to `[]`, and it will only run once.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getActorInfo(id).then(val => setActorInfo(val));
}, []);
```

This will be equivalent to the class-based `componentDidMount`.

If your hook has a dependency, you add it to the array. Then the effect will check to see if anything in your dependency array has changed, and only run the hook if it has.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // You may want to check that id is truthy first
  if (id) {
    getActorInfo(id).then(val => setActorInfo(val));
  }
}, [id]);
```

The resulting effect will be run anytime `id` changes, and will only call `getActorInfo` if `id` is truthy. This is an equivalent to the class-based `componentDidMount` *and* `componentDidUpdate`.

You can read more about the [`useEffect` hook here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: `id` is a prop, so `id` should be in the array (e.g. when `id` changes, change `actorInfo`).

Comment: Don't count on `useEffect` to be satisfied with an empty array though. If not providing it with the appropriate depts unexepcted behavior may occur. This is a great read if you have an extra minute: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Adding these as dependencies worked [id, getActorInfo] Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are still not checking if the component is mounted before you set the state. You can use a custom hook for that:

```
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
```

Then in your component you can do:

```
const isMounted = useIsMounted();

useEffect(() => {
  getActorInfo(id).then(
    val => isMounted && setActorInfo(val)
  );
}, [getActorInfo, id, isMounted]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cleanup useEffect like

```
useEffect(() => {
    getActorInfo(id).then(val => setActorInfo(val));

    return () => {
        setActorInfo({});
    }
},[]);
```

have a look at this [article](https://dev.to/iquirino/react-hook-clean-up-useeffect-24e7). It explains you why to cleanup useEffect.

Comment: the returned function will only run when the component is unmounted.

Comment: yes, it needs a second argument and empty array as argument.